# Setup auto scaling elasticsearch behind GCP load balancer

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I have setup the [Elasticsearch Certified by Bitnami on GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/elasticsearch)
Which I would link to put behind the [HTTP(S) Load Balancing on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) for auto scaling propose. What I have done is create snapshot and use it to create image for instance template. But the Instance group continuous return "instance in being verified" and "Recreated instance" for long time do I don't know where the problem is so I design to use the default instance template from GCP instead.

My question is, when the new node created of when the data in elasticsearch updated how can I sync data between node in the GCP load balancer? Think about when there is high traffic and load balancer created the new coming node, and when the query come in from load balance how the new node have the exactly same data with the existing node or when the new index come in, all the node get the new index.

PS I dont mind for the delay if it less than 5 mins it is acceptable.

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

In GCP, if you want to sync your data between nodes, we recommend using a centralized location to store your data. You can use Cloud Storage, Cloud SQL, Cloud File System etc. You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) to find more options for the data storage. Then you can create an instance template that specifies that when any instance is created it will use the [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images) and has access to that centralized database. This is a recommended workaround rather than replicate new instances with data. You can find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612673/10415226) for the similar kind of thread.

For your Elasticsearch setup, I'll recommend deploying an [Elasticsearch Cluster](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/elasticsearch-cluster?q=elasticsearch&id=14e18082-cdf8-4754-a32a-5be93477297d) that provides multiple VMs that you can customize the configuration. If deploying cluster, this other [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40432614) suggest that is not not necessary to use a load balancer as Elasticsearch handles the load between the nodes.

Comment: So, from my understanding. I need to recreate the instance template every time the new data entry / update then use the template to create new node. Is that correct?

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can use Elasticsearch Cluster.